# How can i change a value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the folowing code:

```
var price1 = (length1 * width1) * priceSM / 10000;
if (price1 < 10) {
    alert("Size too small");
    return;
}
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = Math.round(price1);
```

What I need to do:

If price 1 < 10 alert AND then price1 = 10, but if price1 = 0, or bigger than 10, that's fine.

`length1` and `width1` are INPUTS

Please help, I'm at very beginning with javascript.

Comment: Since they are INPUTS you'll need convert to int or float before do the math; parseFloat(), parseInt()

Comment: @Pablo  Even if the inputs are string, you will find parseFloat & parseInt are actually not required here.. :)

Comment: @Keith never rely on implicit coercion.  90% of the JS "WAT?!" behaviours are caused by it.

Comment: @Alnitak  Never said you should, but pointing out it's not what causing the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the alert when the price is zero, add that in the condition with the `&&` operator:

```
price1 > 0 && price1 < 10
```

To set the price to 10 in that case, add this to the `if` block:

```
price1 = 10
```

To really show the modified price (10), you should remove the `return` statement from that `if` block. That way the code will continue to execute the last statement.

Finally, not really a problem, but it is better to use the `textContent` property instead of the `innerHTML` property when you intend to assign something that is plain text and not HTML.

So your code then becomes:

```
var price1 = (length1 * width1) * priceSM / 10000;
if (price1 > 0 && price1 < 10) {
    price1 = 10
    alert("Size too small");
}
document.getElementById('result1').textContent = Math.round(price1);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I understand well what you want. 
Try this ?

```
var price1=(length1*width1)*priceSM/10000;
if(price1 < 10 && price1 != 0){
    alert("Size too small");
    price1 = 10;
    return;
}
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML=Math.round(price1);
```

If you want to update your element "result1" with price1 when < 10 then just remove "return;"

If it isn't what you want, please tell us and post all function's code please.

Answer (score -1):

Using .value property you are able to set the value.

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Hello World...";
```

Comment: What is `myText` and where did you get the information that it does not have the `innerHTML` property?

Comment: @trincot mytTest is the Id value of the textbox 
<input type="text" id="myTest">

Comment: It is nowhere mentioned in this question. Did you intend to answer a different question maybe and put it here by accident?